# Page made in Flexbox showing differently in Chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The images in the class thumbnail in Chromium are showed bigger than in  Firefox. Why this problem? Seems like that Flexbox not working correctly in Chrome. Thank you in advance!

```css
.thumbnail {
  display: flex;
}

.thumbnail img {
  flex: 1;
}

.immagine {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="immagine">
 <img src='https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/building-blocks/gallery/images/pic2.jpg' alt="">
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src='https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/building-blocks/gallery/images/pic2.jpg' alt="">
  <img src='https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/building-blocks/gallery/images/pic2.jpg' alt="">
  <img src='https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/building-blocks/gallery/images/pic2.jpg' alt="">
  <img src='https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/building-blocks/gallery/images/pic2.jpg' alt="">
  <img src='https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/building-blocks/gallery/images/pic2.jpg' alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Well known bug in Chrome, you can fix it with: `width: 100%;
height: 100%;
min-width: 0`, but then you don't even need `flex: 1`